# What is the limit of $E[X^p]$ as $p$ goes to infinity where $0\leq X \leq 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the limit of $E[X^p]$ as $p$ goes to infinity where $0  \le X \le 1$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For $0\le x\le 1$, $x^p\to0$ unless $x=1$ in which case $x^p\to1$.

So $X^p$ tends to the indicator function of the event $X=1$.

By dominated convergence, $E(X^p)\to P(X=1)$.